# How to create-hosted-configuration-version for aws appconfig

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-app-config

In AWS AppConfig I created application `Testing` and configuration profile `TestingFlags`. I want to create hosted configuration version using CLI.

```bash
aws appconfig create-hosted-configuration-version --application-id APP_ID --configuration-profile-id PROF_ID --content eyJ0ZXN0IjogeyJlbmFibGVkIjogZmFsc2V9fQ== --content-type "application/json" out
```

As a result I got the following error:

```
An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the CreateHostedConfigurationVersion operation: Error invoking extension AppConfig Feature Flags Helper: Invalid 'Content' data
```

P.S. `eyJ0ZXN0IjogeyJlbmFibGVkIjogZmFsc2V9fQ==` is the base64 decoded string `{"test": {"enabled": false}}`

Probably content should be structure in some specific way. I read this guide https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appconfig/latest/userguide/appconfig-creating-configuration-and-profile.html#appconfig-creating-feature-flag-configuration-commandline

I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Documentation example was incorrect. Correct form is:

```bash
aws appconfig create-hosted-configuration-version --application-id APP_ID --configuration-profile-id PROF_ID --cont
ent BASE_64_CONTENT --content-type application/json output.json
```

Where `BASE_64_CONTENT` is `base64` encoded data, in a form:

```json
{
  "flags": {
    "flagkey": {
      "name": "flagkey"
    }
  },
  "values": {
    "flagkey": {
      "enabled": false
    }
  },
  "version": "1"
}
```